# Generic function that returns generic type with recursive property

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a generic function that takes in an array of values and builds a tree structure. The output of the function should return the same properties as the generic type but with an additional recursive `children` property.

As an example:

```js
const items = [
  { id: 1, path: 'a', name: 'path1' },
  { id: 2, path: 'a,b', name: 'path2' },
  { id: 3, path: 'a,b,c', name: 'path3' },
];
interface Example {
  id: number;
  path: string;
}
export function test<T extends Example>(items: T[]) {
  // for brevity ... build the tree
  // I copy each item into a new object and add the children: { ...item, children: [] as ??? } as ???
  return tree;
}
```

In the above example one of the tree items would be:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  path: 'a',
  name: 'path1',
  children: [{ id: 2, path: 'a,b', name: 'path2', children: [ {...} ] }]
}]
```

However, I am not sure how to specify the return type. I'd like all the same properties to be available plus the children array for however many levels deep the children go. I tried something like: `(T & {children: T})[]` but that only goes one level of children deep.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are we supposed to parse the path property string literal type to determine the output type? Or are you just looking for something general like `type MyTree<T> = T & {children: MyTree<T>[]}`?

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WGbkXm)? Are you looking for that?  If so I could write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for! Thought I had to use the T in the generic function to create a recursive type. Also didn't know about the ^?  feature in the playground, very neat, thank you.

Comment: Okay I'll write an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type you're looking for is probably:

```
type MyTree<T> = T & { children: MyTree<T>[] }
```

where we have to give the type a name `MyTree<T>` so that we can refer to it recursively.  It's `T` [intersected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with an object containing a `children` property which is itself an array of `MyTree` elements. Now that you have a name for the type you can use it:

```
declare function test<T extends Example>(items: T[]): MyTree<T>[];
```

---

Let's test it out with your `items`:

```
const tree = test(items);
// ^? const tree: MyTree<{ id: number; path: string; name: string; }>[]
```

That looks like the right type, and now TypeScript is happy with processing it like

```
for (const t of tree) {
    console.log(t.name);
    for (const c of t.children) {
        console.log(c.name); // etc
    }
}
```

Or recursively like

```
function getNames(x: MyTree<{ name: string }>[]): string[] {
    return x.flatMap(t => [t.name, ...getNames(t.children)]);
}    
getNames(tree); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/MYewdgzgLgBAllApgWwjAvDA2gKBvmAb3gBMAuGARgBoYAHAQygAsKByBt2sB5Rdxi0psYAX2p4CxOORgAmWoNYwO1AEZcYPPgKbM5I8ZPzTZAZkV72DddWCbt-FUrOGJAXQDcOOGCQAnADMGYEQYAFEAD146ABswwmNSCjAAV2Q1RH9vAnorGGh-XwBzb1EcHCgATzowgFkqgBV-REQAHkaAPgwYRpgAMiIYYGY4WJIWsAoG5taOzqx3MQqSRGBYhhaYQNSwYCg4cBgkaA6YREikMBI0KJj4zoAKBBQICkbFgEppppb2rsW3hwoEgsCgfx6JygzyQqE+3gA9AiYAA9AD8w3A0GOfx+s3aphS6Uy2TyLAohRKni0vCclLApTEC3cFR2ewOR2KiCgADlaRBHpE8X82sRHBTwSUmV8JUUGYsiEkWlBUv4wDBIgA6QIbKB1Bh0R6wdDdLBQTWOWia61c3n8o2akZjCaIMCfdzwnDlVkgfwwR4g7GwECBHGtT6K3KBkDxTWxEDFB2OT25QK+-2B2DAGAh46O0bjSYRxK5KNYmOIOMJgMW2nwmBI85QYBJcre218vgC8Hh6mNkAAawYVQqQA)